# Show progress in lemmatization

Tags: gensim, lemmatization

following script is used to lemmatize a given input column with text:

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
from gensim.utils import lemmatize
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
STOPWORDS = list(STOPWORDS)

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/0SEv1RMf')

def lemmatization(s):
    result = []
    # lowercase, tokenize, remove stopwords, len>3, lemmatize
    for token in lemmatize(s, stopwords=STOPWORDS, min_length=3):
        result.append(token.decode('utf-8').split('/')[0])
    # print(len(result)) <- This didn't work.
    return result

X_train = data.apply(lambda r: lemmatization(r['text']), axis=1)
print(X_train)
```

**Question:**

**How can I print the progress of the lemmatization progress?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a variable into the lemmatization function to keep track of the number of times it was called - and then print it every 1000 iterations or so. I have wrapped it in a list below so the int can be passed by reference rather than by value.

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
from gensim.utils import lemmatize
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
STOPWORDS = list(STOPWORDS)

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/0SEv1RMf')

iteration_count = [0]

def lemmatization(s, iteration_count):
    result = []
    # lowercase, tokenize, remove stopwords, len>3, lemmatize
    for token in lemmatize(s, stopwords=STOPWORDS, min_length=3):
        result.append(token.decode('utf-8').split('/')[0])
    # print(len(result)) <- This didn't work.

    iteration_count[0] += 1

    if iteration_count[0] % 1000 == 0:
        print(iteration_count[0])

    return result

X_train = data.apply(lambda r: lemmatization(r['text'], iteration_count), axis=1)
print(X_train)
```

Comment: This seems to print every processed line, correct? Somehow it doesn't work for every 1000th step.

Comment: Perfect. But is there a way to do this without passing iteration_count to `lemmatization` in the apply function? At best, I like to have everything in the function itself.

Comment: You could use a global variable - otherwise I don’t think it’s possible.

Comment: Do you think this also works with a progress bar, given we know len(data)?